# To check if array value is NULL i.e. has been set or not

Tags: c, arrays, null

The array takes the garbage value if it is not initialized. To check whether the array is `NULL` we will use `NULL` or `0` to initialize the array while declaring.

If the user inserts the value 0 for an array say a[1]=0 and he didn't give the value for `a[3]` but both `a[1] = 0` `a[3] = 0`.

Without initializing the array as `NULL`

```
 #include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int i, a[5];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[3] = 4;
    a[4] = 5;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

here `a[2]` has some garbage value.

Initializing the array to `NULL` or `0`

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int i, a[5] = {0};
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[3] = 4;
    a[4] = 5;
    for (i = 0 ; i  <5 ; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }       
}
```

Here `a[2]` is not inserted but it takes the value `0`

*If the user's input is* `0` *(here `a[0] = 0`) then how can he actually know whether the value is inserted or not*

Comment: What do you want to say ?

Comment: You actually can't, your first program invokes *undefined behavior* because  you print an uninitialized value. If you are on linux try `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./your-program`. And you can't assign `NULL` to an array you can't assign any thing to it in fact.

Comment: This is a common problem. Sometimes one can find a value that cannot occur naturally -- for example, an account balance could be initialized to INT_MAX (at least on a 64 bit system that's an impossible value). In many cases extreme values can be taken as "not assigned" indicators; but care must be taken to document properly. If that is not possible, one has to define a data structure { bool, int } which keeps track of the value's status. One could also use pointers initialized to NULL and allocated only upon assignment; NULL would then mean "uninitialized".

Comment: Nitpick: In the context of C, integer array can never be `NULL`. Array can contain zero `0` integer values, and only pointers can be `NULL`.

Comment: @user694733: This is not nit-picky, but an important difference. `NULL` is likely `#define NULL ((void *)0)`, so assigning to an integer should generate a compiler warning at least. It might als be reported by static checker programs like lint. OTOH, pointer should always be zeroed using `NULL`, not `0`. This lessons has even be learned by C++ (`nullptr`, using `0` is deprecated).

Comment: @Olaf, `NULL` is defined as the integer `0` for backward compatibility reasons.  In old plain C compilers (pre-ansi) you could intermix pointer values and integer only for NULL valued... but then ANSI came, and invented the `void *` type.  Even in ANSI, you can assign `0` integer to a pointer value, and even Stroustrup in C++ discourages the use of `NULL` in favor of using plain `0` to assign null pointer value.

Comment: @LuisColorado: This is wrong. gcc - for instance - defines `NULL`exactly as I wrote in C mode and that is common for most true C compilers (or those which use proper C libraries). Only for C++, it is defined `0`, but I never wrote to use it in C++, but to use **`nullptr`** which was introduced with C++11 for exactly the reason to remove the dualtity of `0` being `int` **and** a _null pointer constant_. Note that in C++, (void *) has to be cast to the actual type, which is the reason it does not use `(void *)0`.

Comment: "here a[2] has some garbage value." is the result of undefined behavior.  Referencing an uninitialized non-character may simply crash the program.

Comment: Guys my question is actually not about NULL or 0; Actually if a user enters a value of an array as 0 ie a[1]=0 then how can he actually check whether it is empty or not.

Comment: @chux if i check whether a[2] is empty then it becomes false actually.What to do to make it true.

Comment: "if i check whether a[2] is empty then it becomes false actually" -->  This is "undefined behavior" (UB).  It may be "false" today and 7 tomorrow.  It may crash the program - it may be false forever.  The compiler is not guaranteed to return false when code attempts to do something not specified by the C language.  Uninitialized data is not only of an unknown state, it is also untestable without risking UB.

Answer (score 1):

Problematic first is that you seem to have a misunderstanding about `NULL`and `0`. In C `NULL` is usually the number 0, but made to something that fits to any type. So, although you shouldn't rely on it nor use it at all, `int i = NULL` is the same as `int i = 0`. And this leads to the general problem:

### Convention of a "NULL"/"OPTIONAL"/"NIL"/"NOT_SET" value

For pointers this can easily be done by setting them to `NULL`, since a valid pointer will have **any value, but NULL**. Doing this for normal types, like `int`, is not natively possible, because if `int` can be **all integers / *Z*** where do you want to put your "exceptional" value?! That's the reason why often pointers, instead of the direct types, are used, or some more fancy stuff like [boost optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) in C++.

So you would have to write something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

int main (void)
{
    int number = 42;
    int *array[ARRAY_SIZE] =  {0};

    array [2] = &number;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        if (array[i] != NULL){
            printf("Position %d was set to %d\n",i,*array[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However be cautious when using the address of `auto` ("stack") variables, usally you will have to use `dynamic` variables, i.e. use `malloc` and `free`.